# python win32com CreateShortcut key for my application

Tags: python, win32com

im try create in python Shortcut to my application whit arguments Shortcut key:
im create this code :

```
import win32com.client
ws = win32com.client.Dispatch("wscript.shell")
scut = ws.CreateShortcut('run_idle.lnk')
scut.TargetPath = '"c:/python27/python.exe"'
scut.Arguments = '-m idlelib.idle'
scut.Save()
```

need add Shortcut key to this, exemple : "CTRL + ALT + A"

Comment: Maybe it helps http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/create-a-shortcut.html

Comment: not have Shortcut Key option :(

Answer (score 0):

The `IShellLink`'s `SetHotkey` and `GetHotkey` seem to have issues, based on posts I found via google (such as [this one](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32com.shell_and_Windows_Shell_Links.html)). The only way around this that I can think of is to use `ctypes` to use the `win32` lib directly.